# Trouble ranging beacons on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I still have trouble ranging beacons on iOS8 GM & XCode 6 GM:

I already tried:

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I also created entries in the info.plist ...

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

And the following method always returns 'false'

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I also restarted, reinstalled, reopened - the app does not show up in Settings > Location ... where you can grant permissions.

What is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: some research on the Apple iOS Developer forum let's me assume: bluetooth on iOS8 GM does not work in many ways ... (air play, beacons, etc. makes a lot of problems) - still a couple of days left Apple!

Answer (score 0):

Check these (also had problems).

Don't forget to add in your files:

1) Background mode on in capabilities

2) `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`

3) `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

4)

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:(id)self];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Thats in the beginning of app

5) `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in plist with *description!*

6) Try to **CMD + SHIFT + K**  (2-3 times) - clear cache

7) **Try to turn off iPhone and then turn on** - he had some cash in iOS 8 - so after 5 times - app don't ask permission to Core Location - that helped me